# ThreadingTCPServerへSocketHandlerを使ってログを送信するとプログラムが終了しなくなります。(Python logging 関連)

Tags: python, socket, python-multiprocessing, logging

## 問題

deadlockのようなものが発生し、プログラムが終了しません。
[公式サイトを参考にして作った、](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network)`multiprocessing`を用いた並列処理中のログをサーバースレッドを立てて一括管理するプログラムで起こりました。

*Ctrl+Cによるエラーメッセージ*

> Exception ignored in: <module 'threading' from '/Users/username/miniforge3/envs/LoggingServer/lib/python3.9/threading.py'>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/username/miniforge3/envs/LoggingServer/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 1470, in _shutdown
> lock.acquire()
> KeyboardInterrupt:

#### 環境

macOS Monterey arm64
Python 3.9.10 | packaged by conda-forge
標準モジュールのみを使用しています。

#### ソースコード

```py
import sys, logging
import socketserver, struct, pickle
from typing import *
import logging.handlers
import threading
import time

SERVER_LOG_NAME = "LoggingServer"

class LogRecordStreamHandler(socketserver.StreamRequestHandler):
    """Read the LogRecord binary and process it."""

    def handle(self):
        """make the LogRecord object from binary and process it."""
        while True:
            chunk = self.connection.recv(4)
            if len(chunk) < 4:
                break
            slen = struct.unpack(">L",chunk)[0]
            chunk = self.connection.recv(slen)
            while len(chunk) < slen:
                chunk = chunk + self.connection.recv(slen - len(chunk))
            obj = self.unPickle(chunk)
            record = logging.makeLogRecord(obj)
            self.handleLogRecord(record)

    def unPickle(self, data:bytes) -> Any:
        return pickle.loads(data)
    
    def handleLogRecord(self, record:logging.LogRecord) -> None:
        """process the LogRecord object."""
        name = self.server.logname
        logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        logger.propagate = True

        logger.handle(record)

class LoggingServer(socketserver.ThreadingTCPServer):
    """The SocketServer which receive Logs."""

    allow_reuse_address = True
    _server_thread:threading.Thread = None

    def __init__(self,host='localhost',port=logging.handlers.DEFAULT_TCP_LOGGING_PORT, 
                handler=LogRecordStreamHandler):
        super().__init__((host, port), handler)
        self.timeout = 1
        self.logname = SERVER_LOG_NAME
        self.__shutdown = False
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(SERVER_LOG_NAME)

    def start(self):
        """Start server as daemon thread."""
        self._server_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.serve_until_stopped)
        self._server_thread.daemon = True
        self.__shutdown = False
        self._server_thread.start()
        self.logger.info("About starting LoggingServer...")

    def shutdown(self) -> None:
        self.__shutdown = True

    def serve_until_stopped(self):
        import select
        while not self.__shutdown:
            rd, wr, ex = select.select([self.socket.fileno()], [], [], self.timeout)
            if rd:
                self.handle_request()

        self.logger.info("LoggingServer stopped.")

def set_root_logger_components():
    """Add stdout to root logger"""
    sh = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    root = logging.getLogger()
    root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    root.addHandler(sh)

def get_socket_logger(
    name, level:int = logging.NOTSET, host="localhost",
    port = logging.handlers.DEFAULT_TCP_LOGGING_PORT
    ) -> logging.Logger:
    assert name != SERVER_LOG_NAME # Avoid logging roop
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(level)
    socket_handler = logging.handlers.SocketHandler(host, port)
    logger.addHandler(socket_handler)
    logger.propagate = False # Socket logger
    return logger

if __name__ == "__main__":
    set_root_logger_components()
    server = LoggingServer()
    server.start()

    logger = get_socket_logger("SocketLogger")
    logger.info("aaa")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    server.shutdown()
```

#### ソースコード実行後のコンソールアウトプット

終了しません。

```
About starting LoggingServer...
aaa
LoggingServer stopped.
```

#### 試したこと

97行目の`logger.info("aaa")`コメントアウトすると正常に終了します。
`lib/python3.9/threading.py`の1470行目`lock.acquire`をコメントアウトすると終了しますが、良い方法ではありません。
`ThreadingTCPServer`ではなく、`TCPServer`を使用した場合は問題なく実行されます。

なぜ、どこで、どのように問題が発生しているのか全くわかりません。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

`ThreadingTCPServer`の`daemon_threads`属性を`True`にすると解決しました。

```py
class LoggingServer(ThreadingTCPServer):
    daemon_threads = True
    ...
```

https://docs.python.org/ja/3.9/library/socketserver.html